# Problema al crear llave foranea

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

tengo un problema con la creación de una llave foránea en la tabla FACTURAPROV en MYSQL. El mensaje es el siguiente:"...(errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")".

Coloco parte del código código SQL a continuación:

```
 CREATE table IF NOT exists EMPLEADO(
  CedulaEmp int (15) primary key not null,
      NombreEmp varchar (50),
      ApellidosEmp varchar (50),
      DireccionEmp varchar (50),
 TelefonoEmp varchar (30),
      CargoEmp varchar (30),
      SalarioEmp int (9)
 );

 CREATE table IF NOT exists CLIENTE(
  CedulaCli int (15) primary key not null,
      NombreCli varchar (50),
     ApellidosCli varchar (50),
     DireccionCli varchar (50),
TelefonoCli varchar (30)
 );

 CREATE table IF NOT exists PROVEEDOR(
  IDProv int (15) primary key not null,
      NombreProv varchar (50),
     DireccionProv varchar (50),
 TelefonoProv varchar (30),
     CiudadProv varchar (50)
 );

  CREATE table IF NOT exists FACTURAPROV(
  IDFacturaProv int (15) primary key not null,
      Fecha datetime,
      MedioPago varchar (20),
      VlrTotalComp int (10),
     IDProv int (15),
     constraint fk_IDProv foreign key (IDProv) references PROVEEDOR (IDProv)
 );
```

Comment: A esto IDProv int (15), prueba ponerle además unsigned

Comment: Dado que tus sentencias son `create table xx if not exists`, ¿cabe la posibilidad de que ya existiera la tabla proveedor y su campo `IDProv` sea de un tipo que no sea `int(15)`? ¿Es realmente necesario el `(15)`?, al final, un `int` es un `int` y quizás eso esté afectando de alguna manera... lo cierto es que el mensaje de error no es lo suficientemente específico. Qué ocurre si tratas de crear el constraint fuera de la sentencia de creación de la tabla?

Comment: De hecho, recién corrí tu scripts sin ningún problema, en [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/178ab), no da errores con mySQL 5.6

Answer (score 0):

Podemos decir de manera simple que integridad referencial significa que cuando un registro en una tabla haga referencia a un registro en otra tabla, el registro correspondiente debe existir. Por ejemplo, consideremos la relación entre una tabla cliente y una tabla venta.

Leer más: https://ingsystemas.webnode.es/bases-de-datos/llaves-primarias-y-foraneas/

Sintaxis del FOREIGN KEY

```
FOREIGN KEY(Campo1)  REFERENCES tablapadre (campo2)
ON DELETE [CASCADE NO ACTION RESTRICT]
ON UPDATE [CASCADE NO ACTION RESTRICT]
```

Ejemplo:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS nomina2;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS departamentos(
cod_dep INT(2) NOT NULL,
descripcion VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
telf_dep VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
ciudad VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
presupuesto FLOAT(9,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
fec_creacion DATE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(cod_dep)
) ENGINE=innidb;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS empleado(
codigo INT(5) NOT NULL,
nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
ingreso DATE NOT NULL,
sueldo FLOAT(7,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 7300.00, 
num_hijos INT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
tipo ENUM("Fijo","Temporal") NOT NULL,
tiempo_contrato TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
dep_asignado INT(2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(codigo),
FOREIGN KEY(dep_asignado) REFERENCES departamentos(cod_dep)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=innodb;
```

Ahora solo debes adaptarlo

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto la sintaxis de la creaciòn de un foreign key en la tabla tutores haciendo referencia a la primary key de la tabla alumnos.  Espero sea de tu ayuda.

```sql
ALTER TABLE `trabajofinal`.`tutores` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk02_tutores`
  FOREIGN KEY (`dni`)
  REFERENCES `trabajofinal`.`alumnos` (`dni`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```